# Not getting the changed linked list after changing

Tags: c, linked-list

I made a linked-list and returned by reference, for some reason after sending it to another function it does not getting back with changes unless I send it again by reference, any explanation why?

if I just send "lst" to the function as lst without the "&" when it comes back from the function I only get an odd list,When I used the debugger inside the function I saw the list the with the even values(which should be also in the main),as I think it should be like that since lst is the base address like an array,or am I wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node* get_lst(node **linked_lst);
node *createList2(node** L);

void main() {
    node *odd_node = NULL, *lst = NULL;
    get_lst(&lst);//get values for the original list
    odd_node = createList2(&lst);//get an odd list
    getch();

}
node *createList2(node **L)
{
    node * tList = *L, odd_lst;
    node *temp_odd = &odd_lst;
    temp_odd->next = NULL;

    //first element in the list is odd
    while (tList != NULL && tList->data % 2)
    {

        temp_odd->next = tList;
        tList = tList->next;
        *L = tList;
        temp_odd = temp_odd->next;
        temp_odd->next = NULL;
    }

    //first element in the list is even 
    while (tList != NULL)
    {
        if (tList->next != NULL && tList->next->data % 2)
        {
            temp_odd->next = tList->next;
            tList->next = tList->next->next;
            temp_odd = temp_odd->next;
            temp_odd->next = NULL;
        }
        else
            tList = tList->next;
    }
    return odd_lst.next;
}

node* get_lst(node **linked_lst) {
    int value;
    node  *curr = NULL;
    node  *new_node;
    do
    {
        printf("enter value:");
        scanf_s("%d", &value);
        if (value <0) {
            return NULL;
        }
        new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        new_node->data = value;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        if (*linked_lst == NULL)
        {
            *linked_lst = new_node;
            curr = *linked_lst;
        }
        else
        {
            curr->next = new_node;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    } while (value >= 0);
    return *linked_lst;
}
```

Comment: OT: regarding: `void main() {`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()` they are: `int main( void )`  and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Regardless of what some compilers will allow

Comment: OT: for flexibility, it is best to separate the definition of a struct from a 'typedef' for that struct

Comment: regarding: `node *odd_node = NULL;`  this causes the compiler to output the message: `...warning: variable ‘odd_node’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

Comment: regarding: `getch();`   This function is found in the header file: `conio.h` not in `stdio.h` nor `stdlib.h`

Comment: OT: regarding: `new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));`  1) the returned type from any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()` is `void*`  which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful, call `perror( "your error message" );` to output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the operation failed to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `if (value <0) 
        {
            return NULL;
        }`   This is  bad idea because then the pointer to all the `node`s will be lost, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: regarding: `odd_node = createList2(&lst);`  The pointer `odd_node` is not defined anywhere.  so the posted code will not compile.  Suggest: `    node *odd_node = createList2(&lst);`

Comment: in function: `createList2()`  this statement: `node *temp_odd = &odd_lst; is assigning the address of a pointer to `temp_odd`  then this statement: `temp_odd->next = NULL;`  will result in undefined behavior (and perhaps even a seg fault event) because neither `odd_lst` nor `temp_odd->next` points to memory that the application owns

Comment: I get the changed linked list also in `main()`. Perhaps you made an observation mistake. You should state how you tried to observe the list with `gdb`, or add code to print it.